# Copy contain of an unicode file in to the char array in c

Tags: c, unicode, fread

i write a *c* code as following, that copy a file. it works truely for `unicode` files (exe, rar for example), i use of a `char` data-type array to copy file "block" in that. i know that, `char data-type` just can store `1` byte as extended `ASCII` standard.

in `fread()` function, used of `buffer[buflen]` variable as `char` array due to copy a block of an `exe` file (`100` byte) in that, then copy `buffer[buflen]` contain in an other file. how it possible that, a block of `unicode` characters, stores in `char`? why this code works for `unicode` files truely without any problem?

`copyFile` function :

```
void copyFile(const char *src, const char *dst)
{
    const int buflen = 100;
    char buffer[buflen];
    long fileSize, curFileSize, offset = 0;
    FILE *r, *w;

    r = fopen(src, "r+b");
    w = fopen(dst, "w+b");

    fseek(r, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(r);
    fseek(r, 0, SEEK_SET);

    while(fileSize - (curFileSize = ftell(r)) >= buflen)
    {
        fseek(r, offset * buflen, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, r);
        fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, w);
        offset++;
    }

    if ((fileSize - curFileSize) != 0)
    {
        fseek(r, (offset - 1) + (curFileSize), SEEK_SET);
        fread(&buffer, fileSize - curFileSize, 1, r);
        fwrite(&buffer, fileSize - curFileSize, 1, w);
    }

    fclose(w);
    fclose(r);
}
```

`entrypoint` section :

```
int main()
{
    copyFile("e:/1.exe", "e:/2.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

what is the reason of using `char` `data-type` or a `struct` (containing of  `char`) in `fread` and `fwrite` functions?

Thanks of everybody to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any file, regardless of encoding, is just a sequence of bytes. The `char` type can store any byte, so you're just copying the file byte for byte. (`char` is used in C and C++ as both a character type and a numeric type capable of holding a byte. This can be confusing, but both usages are valid.)

`fread` and `fwrite` are specified in terms of `char` because they read and write bytes.

Comment: Well, `fread` and `fwrite` being specified in terms of `char` is not entirely true, they operate on an address and return the number of `items` transferred, which happens to be the number of bytes only when the `size` of the *item* is `1`, which is what it looks like you intended.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin They access bytes in a buffer which is "reinterpreted as an array of `unsigned char`" (http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread). If I understand correctly the bytes in the file are read into successive addresses treated as of type `unsigned char` and then the buffer is reinterpreted as objects. But clearly they are bytes at some point. (TBH I was thinking they took `char *` parameters but of course they have been `void *` for a very long time.)

Comment: @AlanStokes more explain please with example.

Comment: Suppose you had a file containing the single character '€'. This might be represented in the file as the byte sequence E2 82 AC. If you copy those bytes one by one you end up with another file which also represents '€' - even if you don't know how the encoding works,

Comment: I get what you are saying and I think we are talking about 2 different sides of the same coin. You are taking about bytes interpreted from the file and I'm talking about the functionality of `fread` and `frwrite`. Understanding that, I don't have any problem with your statement, both aspects of the functions are entirely true.

Comment: @David Yes, I think we're in complete agreement.

Comment: @AlanStokes i realized completely, thanks of your example. i test a binary file and i understand exactly that how it's process. how fix this question from stack-site? please help me to mark this question as [Fixed].

Comment: Please to all, don't confuse utf characters with the encoding used.  UTF is normally encoded in utf-8, utf-16 or even utf-32.

Comment: @Luis What makes you think we are? My example actually used UTF-8, but it's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @AlanStokes, well, you issued the sentence that says the `€` symbol is encoded (in utf-8 only) as the sequence `0xe2 0x82 0xac`.  The EURO symbol is indeed `U+20AC`, which is encoded as you said only in UTF-8 encoding, but as the 16bit quantity `0x20ac` in UTF-16 and `0x000020ac` in  UTF-32  The encoding is completely relevant to the question, because the `€` sign should be encoded as `0x20 0xac` in a utf-16 bigendian and as `0x00 0x00 0x20 0xac` in a utf-32 bigendian encoding (reversed order for little endianness)  There's even a utf-7 encoding, that makes things more complicated.

Comment: @Luis Look again. My comment deliberately doesn't mention utf8, precisely because the encoding is irrelevant; copying the bytes copies any encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the file you are reading will probably be *encoded* with the utf-8 encoding, which makes the utf chars in the range `U+0000`---`U+007f` the same as their ASCII counterparts (this allows reading normally, even if you don't have a UNICODE compliant reader).  The characters in the `iso-latin-?` set, map normally into two character sequences, and characters like `€` into three character sequences or more.  **As long as you don't modify the data you are reading, it doesn't matter the kind of data stored ---begin it binary or textual, or the encoding used---, the copy will be exactly equal than the original** (or you will have to look into your code, because it is changing the copy, making it to appear different than the original)

Normally, you will not have any problem, as long as you don't break any of these sequences (which means they came together to the file and you wrote them separately ---to different places--- on the copy) This doesn't happen in a file copy normally.  Determining the beginning of a UTF-8 or UTF-16 character is relatively easy, as all characters in a UNICODE encoding can be identified, either going forward or backwards in the data stream.

For UTF-8, the characters are composed of a first character, which encodes the number of bytes on this character, and a tail of `n-1` such characters (again, easily detectable)  The first character will be `0b110xxxxx` (`0b` means the octet in its binary representation from now on) for a two byte character, `0b1110xxxx` for a three byte, and so on up to `0b1111110x` for a six bytes character) the rest of characters that follow it, are encoded as `0b10xxxxxx`.  If you go forward, once you se a byte with the MSB set, you know you are in front of a multibyte sequence, you have to count the number of ones on top before the first `0` and you have the number of bytes that compose the character.  Going backwards, you first encounter a `0b10xxxxxx` char, and you have to go backwards until you get a `0b11xxxxxx` char, which will be the first char in a sequence.  Then you use the first procedure again.

In UTF-16 the procedure is almost the same.  Characters under `0x10000` are encoded as one 16 bit number, and characters equal or above are encoded using a surrogate pair of 16 bit numbers, they have the following pattern: `0b110110xxxxxxxxxx` for the first 16bit of the pair, and `0b110111xxxxxxxxxx`for the second.  This time, you have to substract `0x10000` to the UTF character number before you get the x's that go in the `xxxx...` part of the two 16bit quantities, but the procedure is similar to the used in utf-8.

In `UTF-32` encoding, all the characters are stored as 32bit quantities, so for the moment there's no plan for multisequence encoding.  All characters are transmitted as 32bit quantities.  At the moment of this writting, the standard is V8.0 and incorporates 1,114,112 code points.

When another UTF encoding is used, for example, UTF-16, all characters are encoded as 16bit quantities, that could change for example if you read them in a little-endian architecture, but you wrote them in a big-endian architecture (you should swap each two bytes for the characters to conserve their UTF values in the target architecture) but again, there can be tricks to cope with this (there's a BOM special signature that allows to check with endianness is being used in the data) so, as long as you copy a file, byte by byte, no reordering of characters is done and the final image is exactly the same as the one you had previously, so UTF should not be concerned.

In variable length encodings ([utf-5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-jseng-utf5-01), [utf-7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2152), utf-8 and utf-16) the problem arises if you break one of the multiple sequences that map into the actual UTF codes, because this makes the character non-recognizable by the decoding process (it becomes an illegal character) and then you normally get some special character in the output, signalling the invalid character detected.  In constant length encodings (utf-32) you get a broken char only if you split your file at a non multiple of 32bits boundary.

UTF was designed with the aim of being an efficient way to store and send a practically unbound set of characters, and to achieve this, it maps (or tries to map) the most common characters as one byte, augmenting the lenght as more specific or rare characters are selected.

The main source of information about UNICODE is at [UNICODE FORUM](http://unicode.org/), where you will find specifications, guidelines and even character maps for the full UNICODE range.  UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 encodings are described here.  For [utf-5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-jseng-utf5-01) and [utf-7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2152), you have to follow the above links.